# Ошибка успеха и неудачи AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Я записываю данные из формы в базу через ajax

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Введите число" required>
<button>Отправить</button>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/form_to_db.php",
      method: 'post',
      data: {
        'number' : $('input[name="number"]').val()
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        if(data.success == true){
          console.log(data);
          console.log('Изменения сохранены');
          // jQuery.jGrowl('Изменение сохранены', { life: 5000});
        } else {
          // jQuery.jGrowl(data.error, { life: 5000});
          console.log(data);
          console.log('Пожалуйста, введите число!');
        }
      },
      error: function(data){
        // jQuery.jGrowl(e.responseText, { life: 5000});
        console.log(data);
        console.log('Заполните поле!');        
      }
    })
  })
})
```

**php**

```
if (isset($_POST["number"])) { 

    $number = $_POST["number"];
    // print_r($number);

    if (!empty($number)) {
        // проверяем на число
        if (is_numeric($number) == true) {
            $content = new Content();
            $new_content = $content->addNumberFromForm($number);
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>'false'));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error'=>'empty'));
    }
}
```

Всё работает, данные записываются в базу. НО(!!!), ответ `ajax` всегда один.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я ошибся и куда копать?

Comment: Надо понимать, что всё, что пришло из формы - имеет строковый тип.... Если хочется точный: надо либо кастовать перед отправкой, либо формировать json (хотя для перевода данных из формы в json тоже придётся конфертировать)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так.

```
success: function(data){
  if (data.success == 'true') {
      console.log('Изменения сохранены');
  } else if (data.success == 'false') {
      console.log('Пожалуйста, введите число!');
  } else if (data.success == 'empty') {
      console.log('Заполните поле!');
  }
},
error: function(e){
  // jQuery.jGrowl(e.responseText, { life: 5000});
  console.log(e.responseText);      
}
```